# Why didn't Hashirama break free from Edo Tensei in the Chuunnin exams?

Tags: naruto

**Spoiler Alert: For those who haven't seen episode 366 of Naruto Shippuuden.**

As shown in episode 366 of Naruto Shippuuden, Orochimaru was able to restrict the movements of nidaime hokage Tobirama. But he mentions that Hashirama could have undone his binding at any time.

My question is why didn't Hashirama undo the binding during his reanimation at Chunnin exams?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it was because he wasn't quite fully or expertly revived during the chunnin exams, and was therefore less capable.  I think it says this in the manga itself somewhere, but I don't remember where.  Yes, It's a retcon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will note that Tobirama, in the same scene tells Orochimaru that achieving better fidelity/accuracy/efficacy with edo tensei will be the cause of his downfall, since **this time** they have been revived with nearly their full power.

This strongly suggests that Orochimaru did not perfect edo tensei at the time of the Chunnin exams and that Hashirama was not at full strength and capacity.

Which explains why he did undo the binding at the time of the Chunnin exams - he couldn't.

You will also note that Hashirama doesn't seem to recall Orochimaru, further suggesting that he was not fully revived at the time, though that could simply be his personality...

Comment: It means stronger the jutsu, more the risks? xD

Comment: Would Hashirama ever have known Orochimaru?

Comment: @user2813274 - the timelines don't match. He died before Orochimaru was born.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the "You will also note that Hashirama doesn't seem to recall Orochimaru, further suggesting that he was not fully revived at the time" part then, why would he recall Orochimaru? from what previous encounter could he possibly recall him from?

Comment: @user2813274 - recall him from the first time Orochimaru revived him. The encounter was when Orochimaru was trying to kill the third Hokage.

Comment: @Oded Also note Hashirama remembers Tsunade and taught her gambling. So he might know about her Genin teammates (Assuming he lived that long)

Answer (score 0):

Suppressing their personalities weakens their abilities.
Un-suppressing their personalities makes them more accurate and more powerful due to their near-infinite chakra.

Comment: Welcome, you should try to expand your answer a bit, more details. And some sources, as off right now your answer is pretty low quality. Dont forget to check out the [help] and take the tour, to get a nice introduction to the site ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason has been explained both in the anime and the manga. The earlier versions of reanimation were far weaker then the perfected ones used now. Simply put, the old reanimations were simply weaker in everything compared to the originals or the newer versions of Edo Tensei.